# Add or Subtract minutes from "int" formatted time

Tags: c#

Is there any easy way (using datetime or etc...) to correctly subtract/add minutes to the `int` formatted time, like:

```
1630 - 45 //I want to subtract 45 minutes from 1630 (a.k.a. 16:30), that gives 1585
          //However, I want to get  15:45
```

any simple workarounds?

Comment: What would you expect from 0030 - 45?

Comment: @DavidG why you ask? you know what I expect 2345

Comment: No I don't because that time goes over a day boundary.

Comment: @DavidG I want just numbers (day doesnt matter), in that case: 2345

Comment: i'll try to provide an answer...please make sure to comment before downvoting

Comment: and does the time look like `1630` or `16:30` ?

Comment: TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(0, 45, 0);
            TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(16, 30, 0);

            TimeSpan results = endTime - startTime;

Comment: @jdweng But how to you get from the `int` to a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: @jdweng thanks anyway, but my time is formatted differently, `int`.

Comment: A tick is 100ns so if you multiply by 10000000 you can convert.  But it is not going to give correct answer since 1630 is not 16:30.  Try following :             TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(45L * 10000000L); 
            TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(1630L * 10000000L); 
            TimeSpan results = endTime - startTime;

Comment: Your time is not real time or you are confused.  1630 minutes is 27 hours and 10 minutes.  Not 16 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: You can convert to, a TimeSpan, do your arithmetic, then extract the hours and minutes from the result to reconstruct your integer.  `var resultTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(time/100, time % 100, 0) - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45); var resultInt = resultTimeSpan.Hours * 100 + resultTimeSpan.Minutes`.  This is quicker than converting to a string and back.

Comment: @Joe why you dont post that as answer?

Comment: It's only part of an answer.  A complete answer would need to know how you want to handle values that are not in HHmm format (e.g. 1675), and how to add/subtract values outside the range -59 to +59.  In any case, you shouldn't store times internally in that format.  If they're stored externally (e.g. in a DB) in that format, convert to a TimeSpan or DateTime on input, and back again on output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by converting to a `DateTime` via `string` (and then back again), for example:

```
var time = 1630;
var newTime = int.Parse(
    DateTime.ParseExact(time.ToString("0000"), "HHmm", null)
            .AddMinutes(-45)
    .ToString("HHmm"));
```

Wrapped in an extension method:

```
public static int AddMinutes(this int source, int minutes)
{
    return int.Parse(
        DateTime.ParseExact(source.ToString("0000"), "HHmm", null)
                .AddMinutes(-45)
        .ToString("HHmm"));
}
```

And used like this:

```
var time = 1630;        
var newTime = time.AddMinutes(-45);
```

Comment: ... as an extension method on int!  Aarghhh